# How i can load detail viewcontroller after click on cell(without storyboard)? Mac OS

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

> Ios has didSelectRowAtIndexPath method, but what about mac os?

Answer (score 0):

Your NSTableView has a delegate and you have a few methods to choose from:

[`tableView:shouldSelectRow:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSTableViewDelegate_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSTableViewDelegate/tableView:shouldSelectRow:)

or

[`tableViewSelectionDidChange:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSTableViewDelegate_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSTableViewDelegate/tableViewSelectionDidChange:)

Comment: @gtrgrt on this site you need to accept and up vote good answers.